# How to make a console program doesn't have console window

Tags: c++, windows, windows-console

I'm writing a console program.

The program doesn't print anything.

So, it doesn't need to a console window.

I tried to call FreeConsole() function at program starting point.

When I execute the program from windows explorer, a console window appears and then disappears.

But I wish the console window never appears.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to develop this "console" application (VB, C++, .Net)?

Comment: I suggest changing the question to "Make console program not display console window"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio .Net then create a normal console application and change the output type to Windows application.

Answer (score 2):

Use WinMain instead of main as your program's entry point: [WinMain at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You actually need to switch the project type to console as well - Whether or not a console is required is determined by a bit in the executable header, not the name of the entry point.

Comment: True. You'll probably get a link error if the subsystem isn't set to 'windows' (I think that's how it's called) instead of 'console', but I'm using VC as a guide here.

Comment: I thought a window application project as like you said. But it was a plan B.
Console project never can this? I just want to know well. If it is impossible, I'll change my project type. Thank you!